# Handle submit data is not showing the data from the child form components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, components, submit

maybe the title is here but let me explain the problem. I have a form in react and i want to render four different sections. I want a total submit so we decide to wrap the four subforms in a main form. When we render all the four subcomponents under the Form wrapper just like this:

```
    handleSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log('data', data)
  };
<Form data={res}>
              <GridContainer spacing={24}>
                <GridItem sm={3}>
                  <Form.Field
                    name="type"
                    label="ΤΥΠΟΣ ΑΚΙΝΗΤΟΥ"
                    fullWidth
                    disabled
                  />
                </GridItem>
                <GridItem sm={3}>
                  <Form.Field
                    name="registrationType"
                    label="ASSET CLASS"
                    fullWidth
                  />
                </GridItem>
              </GridContainer>
.....
</Form>
```

The console.log is showing all the data. But when i decide to componentize the four sub forms just like this:

```
handleSubmit = (data) => {
        console.log('data', data)
      };
    <Form data={res}>
                  <SubFormGrid>
    .....
    </Form>
```

where the SubFormGrid contains this code:

```
<GridContainer spacing={24}>
                <GridItem sm={3}>
                  <Form.Field
                    name="type"
                    label="ΤΥΠΟΣ ΑΚΙΝΗΤΟΥ"
                    fullWidth
                    disabled
                  />
                </GridItem>
                <GridItem sm={3}>
                  <Form.Field
                    name="registrationType"
                    label="ASSET CLASS"
                    fullWidth
                  />
                </GridItem>
              </GridContainer>
```

The console.log is showing an empty object. Do you know why is this happening?
The handleSubmit is being called via a button:

```
<Button onClick={this.handleSubmit}/>
```

SubFormGrid contains the above code as i explained in a different component and the i call it inside the Form

Comment: Please show MINIMUM working CODE, there are too many question about your code: How you handleSubmit? Where you handleSubmit, Who are `SubFormGrid` Children? etc!

Comment: check the updated question